# opendj: is it possible to use subentry based password policy for pass-through?

Tags: opendj

I know opendj can create a policy of pass-through in cn=config, but cn=config will not be replicated.

I'm wondering if it's possible to create such a pass-through policy for sub-entry based ?  Thus, replica can work.

And my another requirement is that the pass-through policy can be changed during runtime.

If yes, is there any document or example that I can learn?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Policies can be change at runtime and the change will be applied immediately without a server restart (like most of OpenDJ configuration).
But there is no support for Passthrough AuthN policies as subentries in OpenDJ for now. 
How many pass-through policies do you think you will need to configure ?

Comment: Thanks Ludovic. I can not know how many pass-through policies ,because it probably depends on how many PTA servers on our customer.  But at most 2-3.  My concern is that the cn=config will NOT be replicated for OpenDJ cluster.  do you have any other suggestions? or probably I can develop some code on server based pta policy to dynamically read the pta authn info from somewhere in data entry which will be replicated.